# Using Micronaut Beans in Spring Application

Tags: spring-boot, micronaut

Our application is Spring based and we are planning to include Micronaut also within our application. So, basically, we are looking for a way to have both Micronaut and Spring in our application. The problem currently is that Micronaut beans are not getting exposed to the Spring application context.

The problem we are facing currently is that Micronaut beans are not getting exposed to the Spring application context at runtime. We used the MicronautBeanProcessor but it is not working.
We are taking reference from this article:
[Exposing Micronaut Bean in Spring Application](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html#beanPostProcessor)

Here is the code snippet for MicronautBeanProcessor:

```
@Bean
public static MicronautBeanProcessor httpClientMicronautBeanProcessor() {
        return new MicronautBeanProcessor(Controller.class, Post.class, Get.class, Singleton.class, Singleton.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved.
If your application is Spring boot based (my case) you can refer [Using the Micronaut Spring Boot Starter](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html#springBootStarter).

Also, a very important thing to keep in mind is there is no support for writing Micronaut controllers(Rest endpoints) or anything web tier at the moment(micronaut-spring-boot-starter version 5.4.0).
So, if you plan to use both Spring boot and Micronaut together in your application, the controllers will still have to use Spring-based annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to share beans between Spring Boot and Micronaut I strongly  recommend you to write all your beans as Spring beans and then use the Micronaut-Spring support to let Micronaut discover your Spring beans.

Add the following dependencies to your Micronaut application and Micronaut will discover your Spring beans.

```kotlin
annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-annotation")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
```

Comment: Thanks [@saw303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960875/saw303), I understand this is a pretty neat way to support both Springboot and Micronaut. 
But, our end goal is to completely migrate our application to Microanut. Since this is a big application, we will gradually be doing this over multiple releases. For now, we are converting a few flows from Spring to Micronaut while still keeping the base application Spring-based. That is where we are facing the problem since Micronaut beans are not getting loaded into Spring application context.

Comment: This has been solved.
If your application is Spring boot based (my case) you can refer [Using the Micronaut Spring Boot Starter](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html#springBootStarter).

Also, a very important thing to keep in mind is there is no support for writing Micronaut controllers(Rest endpoints) or anything web tier at the moment(micronaut-spring-boot-starter version 5.4.0).
So, if you plan to use both Spring boot and Micronaut together in your application, the controllers will still have to use Spring-based annotations.